# How to return objects from many to many relation Db - entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to return a List of products of a specific user by user Id, but that seems to not work

My Product class

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public List<User>? Users { get; set; }
}
```

My user class

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required] [MaxLength(15)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }

    public List<Product>? Products { get; set; }
}
```

So im adding and Product to Db, this is working

And then im adding the product to Order by this method
Guid id is a user's id

```cs
    public void AddProduct(Product product, Guid id)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.First(u => u.Id == id);

        var p = _context.Products.First(p => p.Id == product.Id);

        if (user.Products == null || p.Users == null)
        {
            user.Products = new List<Product>();
            p.Users = new List<User>();
        }
        
        user.Products.Add(p);
        p.Users.Add(user);
        
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And this also seems to work:
[image of ProductUser table from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jspj2.png)

So how can I return a List of Products which specific user have?

I've tried this:

```cs
    private Order BuildOrder(Guid id)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.First(u => u.Id == id);

        /*if (user.Products is null)
        {
            user.Products = new List<Product>();
        }*/

        var x = _context.Products.Where(p => p.Id == 1);
        
        /*
        var products = user.Products.ToList();*/
        
        var order = new Order
        {
            Products = x.ToList()
        };

        return order;
```

But this is returning me null, like Adding Products is not working
[Result of this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVVfO.png)

Order class:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
using Application.Api.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Application.Api.Data;

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasMany(u => u.Products).WithMany(p => p.Users);
        });

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

If that's not enough informations comment what I need to add

Comment: Which version of EF / EF Core are you using? Can you also share DbContext definition/ fluent-api configuration? Also, in case you are using EF core you should check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848943/ef-wont-load-data-from-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: @SergeySosunov Im using EF core 6.0.0, and ive added my dbcontext code

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly include the Products for the user

```
var speceficUserWithProducts = context.Users.Include(u => u.Products).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```